# iframe Element itself returns null?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

My Google Chrome insists that my iframe is null. What's weird is that this returns the element without a hitch:

```
iframe = document.getElementById("main");
```

But then when I try to access any property of the iframe it says that I can't get a property from null (even through the element itself can be returned.)

I know I probably have to wait until it's loaded, but adding an event listener doesn't work because it gives me the same error.

EDIT: Some people asked for the context it is in...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="start()">
      <noscript>Your browser is ancient and doesn't support JavaScript.</noscript>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan=10 rowspan=1><h1>TITLE</h1></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr rowspan=2><td colspan=10>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr rowspan=10>
                        <td colspan=10>
                            <div class="codegena_iframe">
                                <iframe src="about:blank" height="300" width="500" style="border:0px;float:middle;" id="main"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <font size="30"><div id="test"></div></font>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my html element:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" height="300" width="500" style="border:0px;float:middle;" id="main"></iframe>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
iframe = document.getElementById("main");

function start() {
    iframe.addEventListener("load", function() {
        alert("foo");
    });
}
```

Please help, I'm at a loss of what to do.
Thanks

Comment: depends when the script runs, before or after the iframe element appears in the document

Comment: try `document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("load", function() {` instead

Comment: FYI, the start() function is called when the body loads.

Comment: Could you post your code that runs `start` as well, then, so we have a little more context?

Comment: make  `iframe = document.getElementById("main");` the first line of `start()` it is being set on script load, not page load.

Answer (score 4):

It is more than likely that the DOM has not been completely loaded when your `start` function runs. You could remedy this problem in two ways.

1. Place your `script` after that `iframe`
2. Attach an event listener to the document that fires your code when the DOM is ready.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('load', function() {
        console.log('The `iframe` has loaded!')
    })
})
```

```html
<iframe src="about:blank" height="300" width="500" style="border:0px;float:middle;" id="main"></iframe>
```

Comment: Even with this example code? What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, recent version.